# How can you scan an image with X++

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, ax

Does anyone know how to scan an image with X++?

Comment: All MS Dynamics AX developers, similar like SAP ABAP developers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to do it directly, but you should be able to call the [Windows Image Acquisition API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139779.aspx) via COM